# SCP as different user

Tags: linux, ssh, scp, remote

I was wondering if it's an option to scp as different user(not the one who connects to remote server). For example, if user A has kerberos ticket to server X and user A has sudo access to user B. Is it possible to scp files to remote server X as user B? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is theoretically possible with use of the [`-S` switch](https://man.openbsd.org/scp#S) with a construct like:

```
scp -S "script.sh" /local/file userA@example.com:/remote/file
```

Where the `script.sh` executes `ssh` will all arguments it gets, except for that it prefixes `scp` with `sudo`. And it would work only, if you make sure that `sudo` does not prompt for a password. What is actually part of my current outstanding question on Super User:
[Allowing automatic command execution as root on Linux using SSH](https://superuser.com/q/1481318/213663).

---

Another option, if you have local host connections allowed for the the "user B" on the remote server, you can use [`-J` (jump) switch](https://man.openbsd.org/scp#J) (supported since OpenSSH 8.0) like:

```
scp -J userA@example.com /local/file userB@localhost:/remote/file
```

With older versions (but at least 7.3) you can use [`ProxyJump` directive](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#ProxyJump):

```
scp -o ProxyJump=userA@example.com /local/file userB@localhost:/remote/file
```

There are other options like `ProxyCommand` or port forwarding, which you can use on even older versions of OpenSSH. These are covered in [Does OpenSSH support multihop login?](https://superuser.com/q/1488097/213663).